# SharePoint List View Filter by [Me]

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, filter, list-view-threshold

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction please.  I have a created a custom list view with a filter on a field called 'User' this is a 'Person or group' field setup to show the 'Name' field.

[image: Person column]

I have 1 entry in my list for the admin account I am using and I have created a custom list view to filter on this user field, I have set the filter as follows:

[image: Filtes]

However this list does contain over 5000 items and when I visit the view I get the SharePoint 'Something went wrong' error even though this should only be returning 1 item:

[image: Something went wrong]

Does anyone know why this might be doing this?

Is this a bug or am I being stupid and doing something wrong here?

Appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: If you have a list with more than 5000 items, you will need to filter it down as it cannot have a listview that returns more than 5000 items due to list item thresholds. It's by design in SQL where you data is stored. Is it possible that you can filter the list to return less than 5000 records you should be fine. Or you could add indexed columns to the list.

Comment: Hi @Christoffer, this is what I am trying to do, I ma trying to filter the list view using the 'User' field, as I said, I only have 1 record where I am set as the 'user' however this is not returned by the filter.

Comment: That’s because SharePoint has to go through all the records to find the single item where ”user” is equal to you. You should be able to index that column from the list settings, just below all your columns. This overrides the threshold as Sharepoint then have a collection of all the jnique values and the query will pass, instead of looping through alla items to find the single specific you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you creating a filtered view with a index column in the large list. Or you can filter based on two columns.

Refer to the following article:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784#BKMK_CREATEVIEWS

Here is another article about the List View Threshold in SharePoint for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-lists-V-Techniques-for-managing-large-lists-13456600-ff66-46ec-a2d2-91736d4a166e?CorrelationId=cb1d0080-5b06-4bab-a7c4-afd9601fe8e0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Besides, here is a similar issue post for your reference:

[How to filter a people/user column that has been indexed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69527/how-to-filter-a-people-user-column-that-has-been-indexed)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to look into the content organization and some of the standard configurations are needs to be changed, e.g. to update threshold limit, update indexing column, minimize the lookup column to be projected in current views etc.

Comment: Can you update your answer to outline how to do this?